# Wrong colors are being displayed - Direct3D

Tags: directx, rendering, direct3d, directx-11

So far I made a very basic cube, but the colors I use are wrong. If I define Red in my Vertex Buffer, then there is *no* red at all anywhere on the cube!

Red goes to Light Green

Yellow goes to Light Blue

....

Some colors like Green, Black, ... are find, just some of them!!
Here's how I define my Vertex Buffer (ignore the `/*UV Coords*/`)

```
Vertex vertices[] = 
    {
        //Front face vertices
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        //Back face vertices
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        //Right face vertices
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        //Left face vertices
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        //Top face vertices
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        //Bottom face vertices
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.5f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow },
        { XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), /*XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)*/ Colors::Yellow }
    };
```

Here I tested it with only Yellow, the result:
[image]

Some info:

Vertex Structure:

```
struct Vertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMVECTORF32 color;
};
```

The Colors Enum is from `DirectXColors.h`. It uses for the colors `XMVECTORF32`.

My really basic Pixel Shader:

```
struct PixelIN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

float4 main(PixelIN i) : SV_TARGET
{
    return i.color;
}
```

My Input Layout Description:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ie[] = {
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "COLOR", 0,  DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };
```

`BufferDesc.Format` has the value of `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A few questions: What does your `Vertex` structure look like? What's the value of `Colors::Yellow`? Can you post the code for your pixel shader and input layout declaration? What `BufferDesc.Format` did you use when creating your swap chain?

Comment: Added info! Thanks for the help! ;D

Comment: You may want to look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/) for some example vertex structures with matching input layouts (``VertexPositionColor``), and example shaders (``BasicEffect`` and friends).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a mixture of `XMFLOAT3` and `XMVECTORF32` in your `Vertex` structure which is inserting extra padding into the structure.

`XMVECTOR` types align to 16 byte boundaries for performance. This would make your `Vertex` structure 32 bytes with a 1 byte padding in between `pos` and `color` to properly align the `XMVECTORF32` data. That extra byte of padding throws off your input layout because you've said the position is 12 bytes followed immediately by 16 bytes which is only 28 bytes.

You can fix that in a few ways. Either:

1. Change `"POSITION"` in your input layout to `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` to account for the extra byte of padding in your structure.  If you are using a `float4` for the position in your vertex shader, you might need to set this extra value (the w component) to 1 before transforming.
2. Change `color` in your structure to an `XMFLOAT4`.
3. Change `pos` in your structure to an `XMVECTORF32` or `XMFLOAT4` and do #1. This makes the padding not hidden.

Comment: Note ``XMVECTORF32`` is intended primarily for creating vector constants. Something like: ``static const XMVECTORF32 s_1234 = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };``. It's not a good choice in a data structure due to the alignment as megadan indicates.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I fixed the issues now by just storing `color` as a XMFLOAT4 and making a function to convert XMVECTOR to XMFLOAT4 on the fly! ;D Thank you again!